# Why Rich Text fields which have "Append changes to existing Test" will show empty cell when i export our custom list to excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, export-to-excel

We have an online classic team site and inside this site we have created a custom list, which contain 2 fields of type rich text + have "Append changes to existing text" set to yes ,as follow:-

[image]

now the 2 fields will be shown as follow inside the list view:-

[image]

But when i export the list into excel, those fields will be shown as empty cells inside excel except for some items it will have values.. so can anyone advice on this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Whether all the rich text fields contain values? Which type of value they contain?

By default, not all format will be kept after exporting to excel.